# How to remove or delete tags in Obsidan.md?

Tags: tags, markdown

Anyone know how to remove a tag or all tags in Obsidian. I imported a bunch of markdown files and they've polluted my tag library - I'd now like to clean it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some code editor for this e.g. Visual Studio Code:

1. Open your vault (`Ctrl + K Ctrl + O`)
2. Open Search (`Ctrl + Shift + F`)
3. In the search bar enter your tag. For example, `#thisTagWillBeDeleted`
4. Press Replace All button (`Ctrl + Alt + Enter`)

Comment: This works great for removing tags in the body of the note, but in the frontmatter there could also be tags as a yaml list, which can be formatted in two different ways. This is more uncommon but when it does happens it makes it trickier to remove them programatically.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but since my import was not high volume, I was able to do this to get rid of all the automatic tag generation in my vault.

1. Type `tag:` in search and it'll show you all the tags in your vault.
2. Open the files with those tags and put these unsorted note in between ``` (3 backticks). This will render the whole note into code and the tags will no longer "exist".
3. You can then sort these notes by removing or updating as you get the time. Remove the code block once you know the note is free from unwanted hashtagged words. Hope that works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an external editor anymore. I just deleted a tag successfully in the complete vault with the [Global Search and Replace Plugin](https://github.com/MahmoudFawzyKhalil/obsidian-global-search-and-replace).

There is also a [Feature Request](https://forum.obsidian.md/t/tag-mass-action-rename-and-delete-in-multiple-files/567) to be able to do it directly in Obsidian.